# Converting Text to Outlines in Publisher 2013

Tags: ms-office, publisher, ms-publisher

In order to be able to print a Publisher file, I've converted it into PDF with the `commercial press options` enabled. However, Publisher does not seem to convert the text objects to outlines/paths.

Is there any way to convert all text objects in Publisher to outlines  (for a PDF file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done in Publisher. The alternative is embedding the fonts in the PDF, but the font needs to be embeddable.

Click the File tab, point to Commercial Printing Tools, and then click Manage Embedded Fonts.

In the Fonts dialog box, select the font, and then do one of the following:

To embed the font when the font has been set to not be embedded, click Embed.

To change the embedding status to Don't embed when the font has been set to be embedded, click Don't embed.

Answer (score -2):

It can be done.

Select your text, then in Text Box Tools, in the Outline drop down choose the black option.

Still with the text selected, right click, choose Change Text and in there change the font colour to white.

Your text is now outlined.

Comment: Ha is asking about vector outlines, not visual outlines.